# How can i scale a cube to only one direction left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

And then only to right and only to up and only down.
The main idea is to scale to one direction.
The problem is i'm not using the editor to add new empty gameobject or a cube.
I'm using a script to create a cube and a new empty gameobject.

In the editor in the scene window i have a cube already. And in the script i'm using this cube to create/duplicate another cube and creating new empty gameobject.

I tried to work like the answer here: The solution method 2.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216454/scale-gameobject-on-just-one-side)

But this solution is using the editor and i'm using a script.
What i tried so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameObjectToRaise;
    public float raiseAmount;
    public float raiseTotal = 50;
    public float speed = 2;
    public static bool raised = false;

    public int x, z;
    private List<GameObject> cubes;
    private GameObject go;

    public bool randomColor;
    public Color[] colorChoices;

    Vector3 lp;
    Vector3 ls;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start()
    {
        lp = gameObjectToRaise.transform.localPosition;
        ls = gameObjectToRaise.transform.localScale;
        go = new GameObject();
        CreateCubes();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (DetectPlayer.touched == true)
        {
            if (raiseAmount < raiseTotal)
            {
                float raiseThisFrame = speed * Time.deltaTime; 
                if (raiseAmount + raiseThisFrame > raiseTotal)
                {
                    raiseThisFrame = raiseTotal - raiseAmount;
                }
                raiseAmount += raiseThisFrame;

                gameObjectToRaise.transform.localScale += new Vector3(raiseThisFrame, raiseThisFrame, 0);
                go.transform.localScale += new Vector3(raiseThisFrame, raiseThisFrame, 0);
                go.transform.position += Vector3.left * (speed / 2) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                raised = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private List<GameObject> CreateCubes()
    {
        cubes = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int a = 0; a < x; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < z; b++)
            {
                GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                if (randomColor)
                {
                    cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colorChoices[Random.Range(0, (colorChoices.Length))];
                }
                cube.transform.position = new Vector3(lp.x - 1, lp.y, lp.z);
                cube.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);

                cubes.Add(cube);
            }
        }

        go.transform.position = new Vector3(lp.x - 2,lp.y,lp.z);
        go.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
        cubes[0].transform.parent = go.transform;

        return cubes;
    }
}
```

But again it's scaling the go var(New empty gameobject) on both sided left and right and i want only to the left.

In my first question it was marked as already answered but the solution in the link is when using the editor and i want to do it by script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my first question it was marked as already answered but the
>   [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217454/3785314) in the link is when using the editor and i want to do it
>   by script.

It is still the-same solution. Create a cube then create an empty *GameObject*. Position that empty *GameObject* to the left side of the cube. Now make that cube a child a of that *GameObject* with `childCube.transform.SetParent(thatObject.transform);`. That's it.

Below is a helper class to do this. It can position the pivot point to any position. I provided `CubePivotPoint` enum to make it even easier. You can also  pass in `Vector3` position as a pivot point.

```
public class CUBE
{
    public enum CubePivotPoint
    {
        MIDDLE, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, FORWARD, BACK
    }

    //Takes CubePivotPoint Enum as pivot point
    public static GameObject CreatePrimitive(CubePivotPoint pivot)
    {
        //Calculate pivot point
        Vector3 cubePivot = createPivotPos(pivot);

        //Create cube with the calculated pivot point
        return createCubeWithPivotPoint(cubePivot);
    }

    //Takes Vector3 as pivot point
    public static GameObject CreatePrimitive(Vector3 pivot)
    {
        //Create cube with the calculated pivot point
        return createCubeWithPivotPoint(pivot);
    }

    private static Vector3 createPivotPos(CubePivotPoint pivot)
    {
        switch (pivot)
        {
            case CubePivotPoint.MIDDLE:
                return new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            case CubePivotPoint.LEFT:
                return new Vector3(-0.5f, 0f, 0f);
            case CubePivotPoint.RIGHT:
                return new Vector3(0.5f, 0f, 0f);
            case CubePivotPoint.UP:
                return new Vector3(0f, 0.5f, 0f);
            case CubePivotPoint.DOWN:
                return new Vector3(0f, -0.5f, 0f);
            case CubePivotPoint.FORWARD:
                return new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.5f);
            case CubePivotPoint.BACK:
                return new Vector3(0f, 0f, -0.5f);
            default:
                return default(Vector3);
        }
    }

    private static GameObject createCubeWithPivotPoint(Vector3 pivot)
    {
        //Create a cube postioned at 0,0,0
        GameObject childCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        //Create an empty parent object
        GameObject parentObject = new GameObject("CubeHolder");
        //Move the parent object to the provided pivot postion 
        parentObject.transform.position = pivot;
        //Make the childcube to be child child of the empty object (CubeHolder)
        childCube.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
        return parentObject;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject cube = CUBE.CreatePrimitive(CUBE.CubePivotPoint.RIGHT);

    StartCoroutine(scaleCube(cube.transform));
}

IEnumerator scaleCube(Transform trans)
{
    while (true)
    {
        trans.localScale += new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

As for integrating this into your current code, change

`GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);`

to

`GameObject cube = CUBE.CreatePrimitive(CUBE.CubePivotPoint.RIGHT);`.

then change `cube.GetComponent<Renderer>()` to `cube.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>()` since the cube is now a child Object of another GameObject.