# Unity collision while rescaling

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, rescale

What I am trying is to make an object being rescaled only from the top.

Here is what I have done using the gameobject parent method I got from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217454/4322337

It is working just fine as we can see below:
[image]
But after adding a rigidbody and applying gravity to the parent gameobject, 
I run into this issue :[image]

why my gameobject go through the ground collider, yet when I look at my object collider, everything seems be ok?

I have also attached my sample project for people who would like to see by themself http://www.filedropper.com/testground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens in my Unity (2017.3.0f3) after I have pressed space for a while. The object with the rigidbody component does not pass throw the terrain.
[image: Print screen at max scale down.]

Is this how it should work? If yes either downgrade or post a bug report with your sample project.

Comment: Well, I was actually using a few months old unity version (2018.2.0f2) and now that I have upgraded to the latest one it works great as we can see here : https://imgur.com/DyVCYUu this version was probably buggy, thank you for taking your time to test with your version!